# Modelling articals and authors in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I need to understand if the way I am modelling data in a Django application is correct. The idea is of a news site that has sources, authors and articles.

I want:

1. `Source` to have many `Article`
2. `Author` to have many `Article`
3. `Article` to have many `Author`

Does the below model do this correctly? I am worried there is a loop on 2 and 3. DO I only need to define the `ManyToManyField` in one of these?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


class Source(models.Model):
    source_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    articles = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Article(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    urlToImage = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    publishedAt = models.DateTimeField(max_length=100)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=5000)


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article)
```

Comment: Is it also possible for an `Article` to have may `Source` or will every `Article` always have just 1 of those?

Comment: At the moment, you just have a design. The code doesn't do anything yet. Feel free to come back once you've implemented a program actually using the model. There's not much we can say at this point.

Comment: @Mast ok I see, I've not used code review before. Do you want to see the associated 'controllers' etc? Also the API I'm using just has one source per article, I did think about multiple sources but thought I'd keep it simple